# Why ChannelFactory-based client application cannot use event-driven asynchronous calling model

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous-wcf-call

I found in MSDN that ChannelFactory-based client cannot use event-driven asynchronous calling model, but a ServiceModel.ClientBase-based client can

How is this justified? What are the reasons for it? Here is the MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.

Comment: If u read the msdn link, that i have provided, they would had said that u cant use event driven asynchronous calling model for ChannelFactory - based client. I just wanna know why.

Comment: The article does not even mention ChannelFactory.

Comment: @hugh - [here is the link stating that `ChannelFactory` isn't supported via event-driven async pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059).

Answer (score 1):

[`ClientBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141.aspx) is a wrapper around [`ChannelFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx). `ClientBase` was intended to work with [`svcutil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733) to enable direct support via the `/async` flag for both event-based and callback/delegate-based asynchronous methods.

The `ChannelFactory` itself has no knowledge of the [Begin/End pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177), so you need to use `ClientBase` to achieve the built-in async-awareness or [create it yourself with `ChannelFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885132).